# Python Pillow Losing Transparency

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to open a .png with Pillow and the output results in the following:

Input:
[image: OG image]

Pillow Output:
[image: Pillow Output]

I believe this has to do with the color opacity, how would I go about making a cleaner output?

Currently, I use Image.open(filename).convert('HSV')

Answer (score 0):

My output image was in RGB, not RGBA, and I converted all images to RGBA